# How to add index range of one string list to another string list

Tags: c#, list

I am new to c# and recoding some python into c#. How would you take a range of one list (list1) and create a new shorter list of it(list2)?

```
python
list1= ["lets", "go", "visit", "houston", "texas"]
list2 = []
list2.append(list1[3:4]) ##new list is ["houston", "texas"]
#or
list2.append(list1[3:]) ##new list is ["houston", "texas"]
```

How would this look in c#?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List < string > list1 = new List < string > ();
        list1.Add("lets");
        list1.Add("go");
        list1.Add("visit")
        list1.Add("houston");
        list1.Add("texas");

        List<string> list2 = list1.GetRange(3, 4);
    }
```

Is there a better way to get list index ranges? And how to begin the index,  list1[:3] or index to end list1[3:]

Comment: `GetRange` takes an index and a count, so the equivalent would be `GetRange(3, 2)` to get "Houston" and "Texas". You can also look into the other methods, like `AddRange`, `InsertRange`, `RemoveRange`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the C# equivalent:

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "lets", "go", "visit", "houston", "texas" };
var list2 = new List<string>();
list2.AddRange(list1.Skip(3).Take(2 /* there is 2 elements from 3rd to 4th*/));
// or
list2.AddRange(list1.Skip(3));
```

Edit: You can extend the list with custom methods:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<T> Slice<T>(this List<T> list, int? start = null, int? end = null)
    {
        if (start.HasValue)
            return list.GetRange(start.Value, (end.HasValue ? (end.Value + 1) : list.Count) - start.Value);
        if (end.HasValue) // not sure [:n] returns last n elements?
            return list.GetRange(list.Count - end.Value, end.Value);

        return list;
    }
}

var list1 = new List<string> { "lets", "go", "visit", "houston", "texas" };
list1.Slice(3) // houston, texas 
list1.Slice(3, 4) // houston, texas
list1.Slice(null, 3) // visit, houston, texas
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that [`GetRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.getrange?view=netframework-4.7.2) is defined as:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<T> GetRange (int index, int count);
```

- Where `index` is the zero-based `List<T>` index at which the range
  starts.
- `count` is the number of elements in the range.

Thus, you doing `list1.GetRange(3, 4);` will yield a `System.ArgumentException:` as `count` i.e. `4` does not denote a valid range of elements in the list.

Further, using `GetRange` is as good as it gets if you want to copy a specific range of a list.

In order to yield a list containing "houston" and "texas" you can call `GetRange` with `3` as the index and `2` as the count of elements.

```
list1.GetRange(3, 2); // ["houston", "texas"]
```

Unfortunately, there's no `GetRange` taking only a "begin index".

Instead, if you don't want to specify the `Count` in `GetRange` then use `Skip` then collect to a list:

```
list1.Skip(3).ToList(); // ["houston", "texas"]
```

Alternatively, if you want to add to an "existing" list then use `AddRange` + `GetRange`:

```
list2.AddRange(list1.GetRange(3, 2)); // ["houston", "texas"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `GetRange` method of `List<T>`:

```
List<string> list2 = list1.GetRange(3, 2); // Take two items starting at index 3
List<string> list2 = list1.GetRange(0, 3); // Take from the beginning up to index 3
List<string> list2 = list1.GetRange(3, list1.Count - 3); // Take from index 3 to the end
```

Or, alternatively, by using the `Linq` extension methods `Skip` and `Take` (`using System.Linq`):

```
List<string> list2 = list1.Skip(3).Take(2).ToList(); // Take two items starting at index 3
List<string> list2 = list1.Take(3).ToList(); // Take from the beginning up to index 3
List<string> list2 = list1.Skip(3).ToList(); // Take from index 3 to the end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Array.Copy() method. This will allow you to copy a specified range of elements in one Array to another Array.

See documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_).